# What does this mean? "If you attempt to circumvent these restrictions, you...put the use of the site by your co-workers in serious jeopardy. "

Tags: support, help-center, rate-limiting, ip-ban

In the Help Center, under *'[Why have I been limited to one question per week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-limited)?*', there's a section: *'Can I request that this block be lifted, or to allow more questions per week?'*. The second half of it reads:

> **Deleting your account, or creating multiple accounts will also not help.** If you attempt to circumvent these restrictions, you risk not being able to use the site **at all** for quite some time, and `put the use of the site by your co-workers in serious jeopardy.` You can lift this block in just a few days with a bit of effort and some good answers, please don't try to get around it any other way.

What does that 'put the use of the site by your co-workers in serious jeopardy' part mean?
Is it some sort of a reference to IP address bans? Or something else entirely?

(And unless it's something glaringly obvious and I'm just blanking, I think that the text should link to the relevant meta/help-center page.)

Comment: The idea is, if you're already under scrutiny for misusing multiple accounts, it's highly likely that other users from your same location will be treated as if they were your sockpuppets rather than other users who happen to share the same location and summarily removed from the site.

Comment: Related: [Jeff's answer to "Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294/241919)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An IP ban would likely be the next step to prevent a person who consistently posts stuff to the network to continue to do so.

So, in essence, even if people who also share your IP (like from an office) are innocent or innocuous about their posting, the bad actor could still cause that entire office to be banned via IP from accessing the site.

There *could* be an impact to those other people's accounts, but (take this with a grain of salt) I think the IP ban is the more likely scenario since the other people aren't misbehaving.

Comment: An IP ban on a CGNAT IP could be *interesting* - entire town blocked...